# discord.py client.create_role error(AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'create_role')

Tags: discord.py

I saw this code in another question.
This is my code.

```py
@client.command(name="관리자", pass_context=True)
async def _HumanRole(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await client.create_role(author.server, name="테러", permissions=discord.Permissions(permissions=8), colour=0xffffff)
    user = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="테러")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
    await ctx.send("테러가 시작되었다.")
```

This is my code, but I got this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command 관리자:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mychi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\helper\helper.py", line 254, in _HumanRole
    await client.create_role(author.server, name="테러", permissions=discord.Permissions(permissions=8), colour=0xffffff)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'create_role'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mychi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\mychi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mychi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'create_role'
```

How can I fix it?
pls write all code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ctx.guild.create_role`. Try this out:

```py
@client.command(name="관리자", pass_context=True)
async def _HumanRole(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name="테러", permissions=discord.Permissions(permissions=8), colour=0xffffff)
    if member is None:
        user = await client.fetch_user(ctx.author.id)
        role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="테러")
    else:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="테러")
    await client.add_roles(user, role)
    await ctx.send("테러가 시작되었다.")
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: @shrimp23 I edited the code, try the new code.

Comment: There's no such thing as `Member.server`, it's `Member.guild`, it was changed ages ago

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @shrimp23 try out the code again, I've edited it.

Comment: @shrimp23 make sure to click the accept button below the downvote button next to my post if this helped you out!

Comment: oh, sorry but I got this error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'